# Redux shopping cart example

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'am trying to understand the example named "shopping cart" giving for redux : 
https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/shopping-cart

In this example you can add elements to your list of items, I tried to implement the function of remove a list of items :

But in the reducers folder there is an `addedIds()` function, I added a case to remove the element of the list but I don't know how to implement that, here is the function : the reste of my code is working fine I just don't know how to delete the product id from the array of addedIds.

```
const initialState = {
  addedIds: [],
  quantityById: {}
};

function addedIds(state = initialState.addedIds, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
        console.log("added ADD");
      if (state.indexOf(action.productId) !== -1) {
        return state
      }
      return [ ...state, action.productId ];
    case REMOVE_TO_CART:
        console.log("removed ADD");
        // here is my problem
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I assumed I need to do something like here :
[Is this the correct way to delete an item using redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582678/is-this-the-correct-way-to-delete-an-item-using-redux)

but I don't know how

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Yeah, that SO question pretty much covers it.   If you want a quick little video lesson on to do exactly this, check out:  https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-avoiding-array-mutations-with-concat-slice-and-spread

Comment: Thank you very much I solved the problem with your vidéo :)

Comment: Killer.  Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can delete some element from array just filtering it out:

```
// ... skipped other cases from the switch
case REMOVE_TO_CART:
    return state.filter(productId => action.productId !=== productId)
```

Approach with `.filter()` function looks very short and produces a new array instance as it required by `redux`.

Answer (score 2):

For those who have a similar problem here is the solution :

```
const initialState = {
  addedIds: [],
  quantityById: {}
};

function addedIds(state = initialState.addedIds, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
        console.log("added ADD");
      if (state.indexOf(action.productId) !== -1) {
        return state
      }
      return [ ...state, action.productId ];
    case REMOVE_TO_CART:
        console.log("removed ADD");

      return [ ...state.slice(0,state.indexOf(action.productId),
          ...state.slice(state.indexOf(action.productId)+1))
      ];
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

thanks to Josh Deeden who found this vidéo : 
https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-avoiding-array-mutations-with-concat-slice-and-spread