# Redux - remove item from array

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have a reduce, so the ACTION_ADD_PRODUCTS call product list, the ACTION_ADD_TO_CARD action call adding products in the card and ACTION_REMOVE_FROM_CARD should remove from the card, but I can't understand how to make ACTION_REMOVE_FROM_CARD return, that when I click on one of the remove buttons, the item should be removed from the card array;

```
const initialState = {
  products: [],
  card: []
}

export const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTION_ADD_PRODUCTS:
      return {...state, 
        products: action.payload}
    case ACTION_ADD_TO_CARD:
      return {
        ...state,
        card: [...state.card,  action.payload]
      }
    case ACTION_REMOVE_FROM_CARD:         
      return {
        card: [...state.card,  action.payload]
      }
    default:
  }
  return state;
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this the correct way to delete an item using redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582678/is-this-the-correct-way-to-delete-an-item-using-redux)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While removing the item, you need to pass additional information with to the reducer, be it `index` or the `id` of the item.

If its index, you can simply use **slice**

```
case ACTION_REMOVE_FROM_CARD:  
      const index = action.payload.index      
      return {
        ...state,
        card: [...state.card.slice(0, index), ...state.card.slice(index + 1)]
      }
```

else if you pass the id, you can make use of filter

```
case ACTION_REMOVE_FROM_CARD:  
      const id = action.payload.id      
      return {
          ...state,
          card: state.card.filter((card) => card.id !== id)
      }
```

> P.S. Also do not forget to return the other state parameters, not just
>   `card` within the object.

Comment: my action like this export const removeFromCard = (productsInCard) => {
  let nextTodoId = 0
  return {
    type: ACTION_REMOVE_FROM_CARD,
    payload: productsInCard,
    index: nextTodoId++
}
}

Comment: but the first solution just remove first item from the array

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to remove items from array in reducer, I usually pass an index as actiin.payload, then just use array.splice(index, 1) to remove the item.
In your case:

```
case ACTION_REMOVE_FROM_CARD: 
    let newCard = Object.assign([], this.state.card)
    newCard.splice(action.payload, 1) 
    return { card: [...state.card, newCard] }
```

Remember action.payload will be your desire index number you pass from the component action. Hope it could helps.